# How I can prove the existence of a bijection $h\colon A\times C \to B \times D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon A \to B$ and $g \colon C\to D$  two bijections. How I can prove the existence of a bijection $h\colon A \times C \to B \times D$?

Comment: $h: (a,c) \mapsto (f(a), g(c))$

Comment: @JiminP: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it: for all $a\in A$ and $c\in C$: $h(a,c)=(?, ?)$.

Answer (score 2):

Define usual projections
$$p_A:A\times C\longrightarrow A$$
$$p_C:A\times C\longrightarrow C$$
$$q_B:B\times D\longrightarrow B$$
$$q_D:B\times D\longrightarrow D$$

Then, the bijection you're looking for is $f\times g: A\times C\longrightarrow B\times D$
where
$$f\times g:=\langle f\circ p_A,g\circ p_C\rangle$$
is the unique map from $A\times C$ to $B\times D$ such that both $f$ and $g$ factor through.

It is a bijection because $f$ and $g$ are, and $(-\times-)$ is a functor.

Comment: Thinking about it in a functorial way seems utterly wrong when talking about naive set theory. When one is mature enough (mathematically) to understand basic category theory, one should be well passed the point where they know that if $|A|=|C|$ and $|B|=|D|$ then $|A\times B|=|C\times D|$.